# How to make many words bold in a sentence with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regex to replace double underscores around a word into a bold tag. But if I have more then one word bolded in a sentence, then it doesn't work. For example:

```
 "this should be __bold__ and __this__ also".replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>");
```

I get this:

```
 "this should be <span>bold__ and __this</span> also"
```

But I would like to get this:

```
 "this should be <span>bold</span> and <span>this</span> also"
```

There is something wrong with my regex. At the moment it only works, if there is a single bold word in a sentence.

Comment: And what about `this should be __bold__ and __th_is__ also`? I think you need `.replace(/__([\s\S]*?)__/g,"<b>$1</b>")`

Comment: If you've gone to the trouble of marking with underscores, why not go an extra step and just use the tags directly?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have a feeling that he is trying to do a markdown simulator or something along that line.

Comment: @Nicholas I share your feeling.  But in the general case, I believe a markdown editor would internally use a _parser_, not just a juiced-up regex (though regex might certainly be a part of the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Regex the quantifiers `+` and `*` are "greedy", this means they will consume as many characters as possible that match the expression being quantified. You can append the question mark operator `?` to turn a "greedy" operation into a lazy operation.

This would make your expression as follows:

```
/\__([^*]+?)\__/g
```

For more information check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Answer (score 0):

Do you replace double underscores to bold tags like `__this__` becomes `<b>this</b>`? You can do this,

```
"this should be __bold__ and __this__ also".replace(/__([^ ]+)__/g,"<b>$1</b>");
```

Instead of `[^*]`, you do `[^ ]` to exclude all whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly different solution, try this regex:

`/__(.*?)__/g`

See the explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/7CVJyd/1

```js
let str = "this should be __bold__ and __this__ also";
str = str.replace(/__(.*?)__/g,"<b>$1</b>");

console.log(str);
```